# Copy Paste the data and then Sort it but having an error

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have been using this below code which copies the data from different sheet and paste it on different sheet and then Sort it as per the requirements.

Now i have been facing an issue that when i use this on `Office 365` it works fine when used this on `Office 2016` got an error. Why the error appear if code is working on 365.

[image]

on the line

```
Sheet2.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range _
("DI1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal
```

Here is my complete code

```
Sheet2.Range("DH1:DJ1").AutoFilter
Sheet2.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

Sheet2.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range _
("DI1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal

With Sheet2.AutoFilter.Sort
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
```

Comment: Do you test the code **on the same workbook**?

Comment: Yes workbook is same.

Comment: The earlier version of Excel may not support `Add2`. Try the simple `Add`.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, and you cleverly fixed Thank you very much  @Variatus can you please share one more thing now that `Add` will work on both Office 365 and 2016. and please post an Answer so i could accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official description of the `Add` method includes the following paragraph.

"This API does not include support for data types, such as Geography or Stocks. To define a sort order based off a SubField of one of these types, see the Add2 method."

Therefore the `Add` method will suffice for all normal uses and the Add2 method should only be invoked if a particular sort order is required that the `Add` method does not support. As a rule of thumb: if you don't specify the `Subfield` property, don't specify `Add2`.

This goes for both Excel 2016 and Office 365, where the difference is that Excel 2016 doesn't recognize the `Add2` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and clarification @Variatus